# 10341 - Solve It WA

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, algorithm, visual-c++

I was working on this problem from the ACM Uva webpage, and I've tried every single input from the forums, and it works perfectly. It keeps giving me "Wrong answer", and as I'm not an english speaker, maybe I'm forgetting something. Maybe someone from here had submitted this solution.  This is the 5th submit I've made from this problem and it's always wrong. Thanks a lot.
EDIT:

Solve the equation:

> > p*e-x + q*sin(x) + r*cos(x) + s*tan(x) + t*x2 + u = 0
> >
> > where 0 <= x <= 1.

Input

Input consists of multiple test cases and terminated by an EOF. Each test case consists of 6 integers in a single line: p, q, r, s, t and u (where 0 <= p,r <= 20 and -20 <= q,s,t <= 0). There will be maximum 2100 lines in the input file.

Output

For each set of input, there should be a line containing the value of x, correct upto 4 decimal places, or the string "No solution", whichever is applicable.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define eps 0.00001

int p, q, r,s,t,u;

long double fdex(long double x)
{
long double res=p*exp(-x)+ q*sin(x)+r*cos(x)+s*tan(x)+t*x*x+u;

return res;


}



int main()
{
freopen("input.txt","rt",stdin);
freopen("output.txt","wt",stdout);


long double x,inf,sup,fx;
while(scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d\n",&p, &q, &r,&s,&t,&u)!=EOF)
{
    long double x1;
    inf=0.0;
    sup=1.0;
    if (p==0 && q==0 && r==0 && s==0 && t==0)
    printf("0.0000\n");
    else if((fdex(inf)*fdex(sup)>0.0))
    printf("No solution\n");

        else 
        {


                do
                {
                    x=(inf+sup)/2.0;
                    fx=fdex(x);
                        if(fx>eps)
                        {
                        inf=x;
                        }
                        else if(fx<-eps)
                        {
                        sup=x;

                        }

                }while( fx<-eps || fx>eps);
                printf("%.4llf\n",x);

        }
}


}
```

[Problem](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=24&page=show_problem&problem=1282)

Comment: I recommend _against_ using `freopen` to create new `stdin` and `stdout`. As it is now you can't really print debugging statements that might show whats wrong. Using normal file handles instead (or even better, streams, as you are doing it in C++) is not that hard or more work really.

Comment: If output needs to come in lines, something as silly as a redundant empty line at the end of input can make your submission WA on Uva. For example, `for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; ++i) cout << arr[i] << '\n';` may not work. You need additional check to not print `'\n'` after the last line. Stupid IMO, but that's how it is...

Comment: Can you tell us your idea and why you think it's correct and should work? You seem to be doing a binary search - why do you think this is the correct solution in the first place? For example, `sin` is increasing in `[0, 1]`, but `cos` is decreasing. Are you sure you can just binary search it like that?

Comment: Ive linked the problem, ill edit it so everyone can read it. Yes its a binary search. And i think its almost correct or there is a value that doesn't work cause the problem give us the answers, but ive tried with other's ppl outputs that were accepted and they are the same.

Comment: I read the problem, I mean could you explain why the approach is correct, so we can be sure it's an implementation bug and not a bad algorithm?

Comment: Because ive tried with diferent inputs from the forums, and all the answers give me the same.I have also tried with inputs from uvasolver, and the outputs are the same as the ones from my solution.

Comment: Wrong answer :) Edited the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is in :

```
else if((fdex(inf)*fdex(sup)>0.0))
    printf("No solution\n");
```

As I belive this fn is decreasing so the replacement will be:

```
x = sup;
else if((fdex(x)>0.0)&& (x==1))
    printf("No solution\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Some things to try / consider:

1. `printf("%.4llf\n",x);` will **round** the answer to 4 decimal places, so `1.23456` will become `1.2346`. The problem isn't clear if this is what you're expected to do - it might want the first 4 decimals without rounding;
2. What [jrok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/947836/jrok) said in comments:

   > If output needs to come in lines, something as silly as a redundant empty line at the end of input can make your submission WA on Uva. For example, for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; ++i) cout << arr[i] << '\n'; may not work. You need additional check to not print '\n' after the last line. Stupid IMO, but that's how it is...

   Personally I never experienced this on UVA, but I wasn't very active there, so you might want to check it.
3. Don't use `scanf(..) != EOF`. `scanf` returns the number of successfully read values, so you should do `scanf(...) == 6`.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help to make eps smaller?

I worry that with the current 0.00001 it might not quite find the root accurately enough to be correct to 4 significant figures.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you forgot the case where p=q=r=s=t=0, but u != 0.

Also, the printf modifier for long double is L, not ll.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing binary search on x (over the 10,000 possible values: 0.0000 through 1.0000) with binary search on f(x): just because f(x) is very close to 0 doesn't mean that f(x + 0.0001) is not closer to 0.